# Updating dynamically created DIVs using Ajax / Django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, html

I was really trying to avoid making the title too ambiguous, but I wasn't quite sure how else to phrase it (as a result of being such a web development noob).

Here is the scenario, I have a template created that loops through a list of objects, each with a unique id. Let's call these objects "clocks" for the example. I've trimmed the template code to the bare minimum for simplicity.

```
{% for clock in clock_list %}
    <div id="clock_{{ clock.id }}"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Each of these DIVs should display a timer/clock of sorts, unique to that specific clock. And each one should be incrementing every second on the page (there will be at most 10 clocks running on the page).

Now I've spent a good deal trying to grasp how to use AJAX for this (and feel free to tell me of any simpler / more efficient alternatives), but I'm not sure if I'm understanding how AJAX works properly. How might I be able to update each of these dynamically created div's independently (or at least have them all update on the same "setTimeout(function(),1000)" duration.

Below is the code I was referencing for AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Ajax(){

    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            document.getElementById('element_id').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
            setTimeout('Ajax()',1000);
        }
    }
xmlHttp.open("GET","content.html",true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

window.onload=function(){
setTimeout('Ajax()',1000);
}
```

I'm assuming the idea would be to use "clock_{{ vice.id }}" for the "document.getElementById('element_id').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responstText;" portion, but how can I use django's template for loops to move through and obtain the contents of a "clock.html" file that contains the contents of the div.

If anybody is willing to help out and needs more details please say so. For the time being I'll continue with this bumpercar programming until I have something to show for it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to have a timer tick down for each div you put on the page?  First of all, I suggest you use jQuery which will make your live much easier.

I've done something similar recently.  In my case, I needed a selector to select the div on the page along with a javascript date I constructed where the ticker was ticking down to.  I then injected a snippet of javascript with every div (you can load this dynamically through AJAX), like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var timers = [];

      // can update data by calling $.ajax or $.get or any of the ajax jquery calls
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% for clock in clock_list %}
    <div class="countdown-target" id="countdown-target-{{ clock.id }}">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      timers.push({ selector: '#countdown-target-{{ clock.id }}', endTime: new Date(year, month-1, day, hour, minute, second) });
    </script>
    {% endfor %}

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function timerTick() {
      for(var i in timers) {
        var entry = timers[i];
        var now = new Date();
        var diff = now - entry.endTime;

        var targetElement = $(entry.selector);
        var countdownTicker = $('.countdown', targetElement);

        // calculate the difference and update the ticker
        countdownTicker.text(new_ticker_text_value);
      }
    }
    // start one tick right away
    timerTick();
    setInterval(timerTick, 1000);
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Calling a web service to return new data that pushes to the timer array will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response. One thing I'm not sure about is this line:  // can update data by calling $.ajax or $.get or any of the ajax jquery calls. What is the purpose of doing this? Doesn't the setInterval(timerTick, 1000) handle calling the method every second? Does countdownTicker.text(new_ticker_text_value) update the content of the div? Sorry for all the questions, I'm still piecing things together.

Comment: Sorry about that.  That area is supposed to be where you do your AJAX calls.  With jQuery it's as simple as doing $.getJSON(url, function(response) { }) (assuming you are returning JSON).  When you get your response, push the data onto the timers array.  I also edited my entry since there was a missing {{ clock.id }} in the javascript snippet.

Comment: Should var countdownTicker = $('.countdown', targetElement); be var countdownTicker = $('.countdown-target', targetElement); ? Just curious.

Comment: I intended .countdown to be the class of a span or other element inside the target element that you would update with each timer tick.  I suppose the .countdown-target class is not necessary in this case.  Also, I realized that I didn't give any information on constructing the date object.  You could use datetime to do that and then output each date part using {{ clock.date.date_part_here }}.  It's useful to know that in JS months start at 0, so you may have to do {{ clock.date.month|add:"-1" }}

Comment: Well, I left out some details for this particular project. I have a list of tuples I'm passing in from the django view. Each tuple contains a timedelta that ideally I want to format into years/days/hours/minutes/seconds, and an the vice object (the site is just going to allow users to track their vices and the last time they "used", just a project to teach myself stuff).   `<div class="clock_target" id="clock_{{ vice.0.id }}"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">clocks.push({ clock_id: 'clock_{{ vice.0.id }}', time_days: '{{ vice.1.days }}',time_seconds: '{{vice.1.seconds}}' })</script>`

Comment: So if I use the dom in the javascript to update the elements of the page, what purpose would ajax serve?

Comment: Ajax is only needed when you are loading additional content as the page is viewed.  If you can create it all when the user first visits your page, you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks a ton, you've been insanely helpful. Hopefully I can get this working now.